# A spinner is made with red and blue sections. The desired probability for RED is 0.75. What angle measure is required for the BLUE section

Tags: probability, education, data-analysis

question: A spinner is made with red and blue sections. The desired probability for RED is 0.75. What angle measure is required for the BLUE section.

Hi, I saw these qs in my practice questions and that's how I answered them.

as we have 100-75=25
25% of the circle would be 90 degrees
The angle measure for blue would be 90.
I'm not sure if that how should do it because my answer looks so basic.
I would appreciate it if you tell me that I have answered it right.

Comment: Solutions to problems don't need to be complicated. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks correct. The only way that answer would be wrong is if there are, say, 8 total sections of equal size. In such a case we would have 2 blue sections and they would be 45 degrees each. Otherwise, I see no issue with your solution.